# Criando um array a partir de dois

Tags: java, array

Tenho a situação aonde preciso construir em java um `arrayC[]` a partir de um `arrayA[4]` e um `arrayB[7]`, onde o `arrayC[]` deve apresentar em ordem o `arrayA[4]` e depois o `arrayB[7]`:

por exemplo:

```
arrayA[4] = {A0; A1; A2; A3};
arrayB[7] = {B0; B1; B2; B3; B4; B5; B6};
arrayC[i] = {A0; A1; A2; A3; B0; B1; B2; B3; B4; B5; B6};
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Os tipos de `arrayA` e `arrayB` são os mesmos?

Comment: são sim, os dois são int

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Há inúmeras formas de fazer isso. Uma das formas é essa:

```
XXX[] arrayC = new XXX[arrayA.length + arrayB.length];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
    arrayC[i] = arrayA[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++) {
    arrayC[i + arrayA.length] = arrayB[i];
}
```

No exemplo acima, `XXX[]` é o tipo do array. Isso pode ser `int[]`, `boolean[]`, `String[]`, `Object[]`, etc.

Outra forma:

```
XXX[] arrayC = new XXX[arrayA.length + arrayB.length];
System.arraycopy​(arrayA, 0, arrayC, 0, arrayA.length);
System.arraycopy​(arrayB, 0, arrayC, arrayA.length, arrayB.length);
```

Uma terceira forma, se o tipo base do array não for um tipo primitivo:

```
List<XXX> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrayA));
lista.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrayB));
XXX[] arrayC = lista.toArray(new XXX[0]);
```

Uma quarta forma, usando `Stream`s:

```
XXX[] arrayC = Stream.concat(Stream.of(arrayA), Stream.of(arrayB)).toArray(XXX[]::new);
```

[**Veja aqui todas essas formas funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/PTQePt)

Comment: Sei q nao faz parte da duvida, mas teria stream alguma forma de fazer isso de forma curta tambem?

Comment: @Articuno Feito. :)

Comment: @VictorStafusa valeu cara! o primeiro método era o que eu cheguei mais perto de fazer antes de perguntar aqui (:

Comment: @LucasMonteiro acho que os agradecimentos foram para o Victor, ele que fez essa ótima resposta :)

Answer (score 4):

No Java 8 em diante:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] b = new int[] { 40, 50, 60 };

        int[] array =
            IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(a), Arrays.stream(b))
                .toArray();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));` ao invés do `for`.

Comment: Valeu @VictorStafusa, corrigi aqui.